# Show only available imports from file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently switched from webstorm to vscode and I am struggling to set it up for my needs.

Right now I am wondering if there is any extension/setting that will show only available imports from the imported file.

Here is an example:

```
import { InternalDataObject } from 'internal-node-module'
import actionTypes from './pay-structure.action-types'

const { GET_JOB_STAMP } = actionTypes

export {
  getMissionFees,
}

const getMissionFees = () => ({
  type: GET_JOB_STAMP,
  promise: InternalDataObject.payStructure.getJobFeeStamp,
})
```

[image]
When I press ctrl + space in the brackets I can see thousands of options, but I would like to see only one: `getMissionFees`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting for that:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"
```

It ontrols whether snippets are shown with other suggestions and how they are sorted. Possible values: top, bottom, inline, none.

Comment: Nice one, also I had `vscode-exports-autocomplete` installed, works much better without it:
`vscode-exports-autocomplete.enable": false`